# Session variable doesn't persist upon postback (out of memory perhaps?)

Tags: c#, asp.net, postback, session-variables

I ran into this problem in a bigger project and I managed to pinpoint and reproduced it in a scaled down, single page scenario. The page has a single button control `btnSubmit` and the code behind as follow:

```
private int n = 100;

protected void Page_Init(object sender, EventArgs e) {
    btnSubmit.Click += btnSubmit_Click;
}

protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e) {
    if (!Page.IsPostBack) {
        Session["test"] = "Hello World";

        for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
            using (StreamWriter file = new StreamWriter(Server.MapPath("/sample.txt"), true)) {
                file.WriteLine(i);
            }
        }
    } else {
        int sessionCount = Session.Count;
        string test = Session["test"].ToString();
    }
}

void btnSubmit_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) {
}
```

The code above does 2 things upon page load. The first, assign a string "Hello World" to a session variable `test`. The second, writes integers from 0 to 99 into a text file "sample.txt" on different lines.
Clicking on `btnSubmit` triggers a postback (the button doesn't do anything else though, just to postback the page). After postback, the value of `sessionCount = 1` and `test = "Hello World"`. That is the expected behaviour and the code above runs fine.

Now if you change `n = 9000` or any large integers, upon postback (by clicking on `btnSubmit`), the session variable `Session["test"]` is null and `sessionCount = 0`. `test` throws an exception since `Session["test"]` doesn't exist. What gives? My development machine has 6GB of RAM, it's unlikely that shortage of memory is the reason since handling a couple of thousands of integers doesn't take much.

Comment: If you put a break point after the 9000 time loop does it hit? Maybe it gets interrupted for asking to write to the same file 9000 times? I bet it'd work if you wrapped the for loop with the using statement, I'd be interested to know why it doesn't work as is though

Comment: writing to text file runs fine. Text file produced with the intended content. Null exception is thrown only at `string test = Session["test"].ToString();`

Comment: Interesting, well I'll stay tuned to see why this is, did you try wrapping the for loop in a single using statement, just to see if that's the cause

Answer (score 0):

I guess that you store your session inProc.

What is happening has nothing to do with the StreamWriter. The application will restart when you compile your code and you will loose your session. The value Session["test"] is gone. This is the flow:

1. Load the page (you know save "Hello World" in the session)
2. Click the button (it works fine, no exception)
3. Update the code and compile (application is restarted and your session is lost)
4. Click the submit button (`Page.IsPostBack` is true)
5. You execute `Session["test"].ToString()` but you have not executed `Session["test"] = "Hello World"` after step 3.

If you change from inProc to StateServer in web.config and start the session state service, then you will not get the null reference error.

Comment: This sounds like a likely scenario, and easy to test if you aren't restarting things each time. Just try it again for n = 10

Comment: Each time I recompiled my codes, I'd make sure to refresh the page first. I've verified that for each recompilation, `Session["test"] = "Hello World"` will be executed again after the page is refreshed.

Comment: Do you refresh the page by pressing F5 or by going to the address bar and pressing enter? If the last thing you did on the page was a post, then F5 will do another post and you would get the exception again.

Comment: I have made sure it's not a post. It's either i pressed the browser Back button before hitting F5 or hitting Enter when the address bar has focus.

Comment: Hmm... that is strange. I have not managed to reproduce the problem. I only get the dump if I do the post directly after compiling, but not after loading the page and then doing a post. I set n = 100000;

Answer (score 0):

you could try switching off object tracking.

Source:http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.linq.datacontext.objecttrackingenabled.aspx